# Sorting in Prolog

Tags: list, sorting, prolog

I have a data structure in Prolog like this:

```
racks =
 [
  [
   (1-1), 1,
   [
    shelf((0-0), 1, [ware_a:[0,10]]),
    shelf((0-1), 2, []),
    shelf((0-2), 3, [])
   ]
 ],
 [
  (2-1), 2,
  [
   shelf((0-0), 4, []),
   shelf((0-1), 5, []),
   shelf((0-2), 6, [])
  ]
 ].
```

One rack has coordinate (x-y) (for example (1-1)) and a cost value and a list of shelfs. A shelf itself has the same, a coordinate (within the rack), a cost value and a list of content (wares, which lies in the shelf).

Now, during the execution of my program, it is possible, that the ordering of racks or shelfs are confused.

For example:

```
racks =
 [
  (2-1), 2,
  [
   shelf((0-0), 4, [ware_c:[50,100]]),
   shelf((0-1), 5, []),
   shelf((0-2), 6, [])
  ]
 ],
 [
  [
   (1-1), 1,
   [
    shelf((0-1), 2, [ware_b:[1,2], ware_a:[10,20]]),
    shelf((0-0), 1, [ware_a:[0,10]]),
    shelf((0-2), 3, [])
   ]
 ].
```

Now, I'm searching for a possibility to sort this lists. They (the racks and within them the shelfs) should be sorted by their cost value (the coordinates doesn't matter).

How can I do this?!

I don't have much experience in sorting lists in Prolog, so I want you to ask, guys!

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the better option, performance wise, should be [keysort](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=keysort/2): make a service predicate (a fact, really), that 'extract' key from term, keysort the paired list, then the same service predicate can 'reverse' and discard the keys from the sorted list:

```
extract_key([A,K|T], K-[A,K|T]).

% note the uppercase Racks. It's a variable!
Racks = [[...]], % your complex structure here
maplist(extract_key, Racks, Keyed),
keysort(Keyed, KeySorted),
maplist(extract_key, Sorted, KeySorted),
% use Sorted in futher processing
```

Less efficient, there is [predsort](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=predsort/3)/3, can be easier to write, using standard order of term, i.e. [compare](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=compare/3)/3, but beware to *not* return the equality, or the algorithm will discard the whole record (predsort, like sort, discards duplicates).

```
cmprecords(R,[_,K1|_],[_,K2|_]) :- compare(R,K1,K2). % beware, discards on K1==K2

% note the uppercase Racks. It's a variable!
?- Racks = [...], predsort(cmprecords, Racks, Sorted).
```

Comment: `maplist/3` + `keysort/2` works out-of-the-box with the super-fast ISO-compliant SICStus Prolog 4.3.2.